# Given a random variable $X$ when is possible to find a probability measure Q s.t $s.t \frac{dQ}{d\mathbb{P}}=X$?

Tags: probability-theory

I'm wondering about the following question

Let $X$ be a random variable on $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P}\right)$
 , what is a necessary condition for there to be a probability measure $Q$
  on $\left(\Omega,\mathcal{F}\right)$
  s.t $\frac{dQ}{d\mathbb{P}}=X$ and how does one find this $Q$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: For each $A\in \mathcal{F}$, define $Q(A) = E^{\mathbb{P}}(X1_{A})$, then check all the conditions in the definition of probability measure